# C# Math.Net Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: c#, python, artificial-intelligence

I was trying to translate this python code for a Neural Network
https://gist.github.com/miloharper/c5db6590f26d99ab2670#file-main-py
in C#. I'm using the Math.Net Numerics for the matrixes and here is the code I've made so far in C#

```
using System;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

namespace NeuralNetwork
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NeuralNetwork NN = new NeuralNetwork();

            Console.WriteLine("Random starting synaptic weights: ");
            Console.WriteLine(NN.SynapticWeights);

            Matrix<double> TrainingSetInput = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] { { 0, 0, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 0, 1 }, { 0, 1, 1 } });
            Matrix<double> TrainingSetOutput = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] { { 0, 1, 1, 0 } }).Transpose();

            NN.Train(TrainingSetInput, TrainingSetOutput, 10000);

            Console.WriteLine("New synaptic weights after training: ");
            Console.WriteLine(NN.SynapticWeights);

            Console.WriteLine("Considering new situation {1, 0, 0} -> ?: ");
            Console.WriteLine(NN.Think(DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] { { 1, 0, 0 } })));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class NeuralNetwork
    {
        private Matrix<double> _SynapticWeights;

        public NeuralNetwork()
        {
            _SynapticWeights = 2 * Matrix<double>.Build.Random(3, 1) - 1;
        }

        private Matrix<double> Sigmoid(Matrix<double> Input)
        {
            return 1 / (1 + Matrix<double>.Exp(-Input));
        }

        private Matrix<double> SigmoidDerivative(Matrix<double> Input)
        {
            return Input * (1 - Input); //NEW Exception here
        }

        public Matrix<double> Think(Matrix<double> Input)
        {
            return Sigmoid((Input * _SynapticWeights)); //Exception here (Solved)
        }

        public void Train(Matrix<double> TrainingInput, Matrix<double> TrainingOutput, int TrainingIterations)
        {
            for (int Index = 0; Index < TrainingIterations; Index++)
            {
                Matrix<double> Output = Think(TrainingInput);
                Matrix<double> Error = TrainingOutput - Output;
                Matrix<double> Adjustment = Matrix<double>.op_DotMultiply(TrainingInput.Transpose(), Error * SigmoidDerivative(Output));

                _SynapticWeights += Adjustment;
            }
        }

        public Matrix<double> SynapticWeights { get { return _SynapticWeights; } set { _SynapticWeights = value; } }
    }
}
```

When I execute it, it shows an exception on line 53 (there is a comment at that line in the code). It says:

> Matrix dimensions must agree: op1 is 4x3, op2 is 3x1

Did I copy it wrong or is it a problem with the MAth.Net library?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: While the Python code really writes "dot", it clearly means a simple matrix\*vector multiplication, not a dot-product. So try that one (the Matrix class I found defines an ```operator *```)

Comment: I tried the * operator but it still doesn't work

Comment: Another thing may be the different interpretation of rows and columns. While it will destroy the math behind, you can quickly test if swapping the order of the arguments suddenly "fixes" either the dot or the \*. If it works, then everything is trasposed compared to what the original Python code expects.

Comment: Ok, itried to swap rows and columns but it doesn't do anything. One Matrix is 3x1 (SynapticWeights) and the other is 4x3 (TrainingSetInput). I don't know how to dotMultiply them correctly together apparently.

Comment: Well, I really wonder what you have tried yesterday, if you are just going to try ```return Sigmoid(Input * _SynapticsWeights);``` right now (according to the discussion below)

Comment: Sorry im not home, I cant check the code right now

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the problem not in the library code. You are trying to perform an element-wise matrix multiplication with the use of `op_DotMultiply` function (line 53). In this case it is obvious from the error message that matrices cannot be multiplied due to difference in their size: the first one is 4x3, the second one is 3x1.

I can suggest to look at the size of these matrices: `TrainingSetInput` and `_SynapticWeights` (look at function `Train`, you are calling `Think` inside of it with the wrong sized matrices). Check if they are generated correctly. And also think if you really need an element-wise matrix multiplication or a usual multiplication.
If you need more info about matrix multiplications, you can use these links:

Element-wise:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Usual:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: I need dot Moltiplication for the neural network to work

Comment: Also the matrices are generated correctly with different sizes and i don't think there is much i can do

Comment: You are generating 4x3 `TrainingSetInput` matrix, passing it into function called `Train`, where in a `for` loop you are calling `Think` function, and again passing there `TrainingSetInput` matrix. Inside of this function your 4x3 matrix is dot multiplied with 3x1 matrix `_SynapticWeights`. Unfortunately, this is mathematicaly impossible. For dot multiplication you really need to have equal-sized matrices. I am sorry, if I miss something obvious, I might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination , how does to the python version works though? In the think function in Python there is the same dot product and it does work

Comment: Have you checked if the python version works on the same very input?

Comment: Yes, the inputs are the same. I basicly rewrote thr pythom code in c# exactly the sams. The python version works perfectly.

Comment: What function is used for matrix multiplication in python? What is its name?

Comment: You can check the code at the link in the post. It uses dot() from numpy to do dot product.

Comment: Well, dot function in numpy performs usual matrix multiplication, not element-wise. And Math.Net analog for this is `*` operator, not op_dotMultiply. So, in your `Think` function try to replace code with the following: `return Sigmoid(Input * _SynapticsWeights);`

Comment: Thank, i'll try it once i get home

Comment: Ok i tried it again (as pointed out bg tevemadar) it now shows the same exception with a different text "Matrix dimensions must agree: op1 is 4x1, op2 is 4x1" what doez this mean??

Comment: Sigmoid now works with the normal * operator. (I also updated the code in the post). The sigmoid derivative now doesn't work